# Use of 'format' in ARM templates

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I want to know the meaning of 'format' in Azure ARM templates. For eg.
"networkInterfaceName": "[format('{0}NetInt', parameters('vmName'))]",
what does 'format' do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what does 'format' do here?

`format` is an in-built [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions) available in ARM templates which creates a formatted string based on the input values.

In your case, it should produce a string like `myvmnameNetInt` where `myvmname` is the value of the parameter `vnName`.

You can learn more about this function here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-string#format.